# MySQL IN clause without quotes

Tags: mysql

I have the follwing simple MySQL query that returns 0 results:

```
SELECT d.name FROM document d WHERE 10 IN (d.categories)
```

"categories" is of type varchar and contains for example "10,20,30".

When I type the IN values directly it works and returns a result:

```
SELECT d.name FROM document d WHERE 10 IN (10,20,30)
```

I suspect MySQL substitutes d.documents with something like this which of course is not what I want:

```
SELECT d.name FROM document d WHERE 10 IN ("10,20,30")
```

What is a proper workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes with find_in_set :

```
SELECT d.name FROM document d WHERE find_in_set(10, d.categories) > 0
```

Answer (score 6):

When you are providing the value as "10,20,30" then it is treated as a single value as against your expected three distinct values. To make the value as three distinct values you need to use the [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function in MySQL.

Also I would suggest you to go through this thread: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)